# Im having an issue entering a last name to an input

Tags: java

I am writing a program to print out the name of a student and their grade. It works if I only enter their first name and I get an Error when I enter their last. I am wondering if I have overlooked something with the String name.

```
package project_2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        String name = input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter Grade: \t");
        double Grade = input.nextDouble();
        if(Grade>=88)
            System.out.println(name  + "You have an A!");
        else if (Grade<=87 && Grade>=80)
            System.out.println(name  + "You have a B!");
        else if (Grade<=79 && Grade>=67)
            System.out.println(name  + "You have a C!");
        else if (Grade<=66 && Grade>=60)
            System.out.println(name  + "You have a D!");
        else 
            System.out.println(name  + "You have a F!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - please always add the *complete* error message you get.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: `String name = input.next();` stops getting input at the first space.  So if you input a first and last name, the first name gets taken by `input.next()` and the last name is still there - and then `input.nextDouble()` tries to use it, but it's not a double, and the exception gets thrown.

Comment: Thanks a ton @DM your comment helped a ton and actually made me understand what I was doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
String name = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter Grade: \t");
```

Then you can take the full name.

Output:

```
Enter your name: Jack Davidson
Enter Grade:    88
```

Please note that, Using `next()` will only return what comes before a space. `nextLine()` automatically moves the scanner down after returning the current line.